# What is this object get destructed twice?

Tags: c++

The socket object's destructor get called twice according to the print statement on destructor. Can anyone explain me why this happens?

Log

```
Connection Emplaced
Socket Moved
From Handle  1
Socket Object destructed and isLive 0
Connection Object destructed
Socket Object destructed and isLive 1
```

Source

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

class Socket {
    public:
        bool isLive{};

    ~Socket() {
        std::cout << "Socket Object destructed and isLive " << isLive << "\n";
    }
};

class Connection {
   public:
     Socket socket;
    
    ~Connection() {
        std::cout << "Connection Object destructed" << "\n";
    }
};

std::unordered_map<std::string, Connection> connections;

void handle() {
    auto& connection = connections["A"];

    std::cout << "From Handle  " << connection.socket.isLive << "\n";
}

void worker(Socket&& socket) {
    const auto& [connection, inserted] = connections.try_emplace("A");

    std::cout << "Connection Emplaced" << "\n";

    connection->second.socket = std::move(socket);
    connection->second.socket.isLive = true;

    std::cout << "Socket Moved" << "\n";

    std::async(std::launch::async, handle);
}

int main() {
    Socket socket;

    worker(std::move(socket));
}
```

Comment: It is called for different objects, it isn't being "called twice".  C++ creates temporaries, you just need to know where those temporaries are.  One place is the creation of the map entries.  Second, print `this`, not just a message in the destructor.  Then this will convince you that the destructor is being called on different objects.

Comment: When I get puzzled by something like this I add debug prints into the copy and move constructors and copy and move assignment operators.

Comment: Add `<< this` to the end of your print.

Comment: One more thing --  If you planned on the destructor to actually destroy socket connections, you will be in a lot of trouble when you are using Socket objects being passed around and returned by-value, as well as temporary creation and destruction.  You are witnessing the dangers right now.  I personally have seen code, where the original coder wrote so much code around this type of behavior of having the destructor tear down everything -- I had to unravel and redesign it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm actually in trouble right now. Having bunch of seg faults. I use move and references everywhere. I couldn't come up with better idea why seg faults happening than this twice idea. I store the socket wrapped inside connection object in the global map. When socket receives disconnect event, I remove it from map. A separate function will be invoked onDisconnect.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It's a quite stateful application compared to most stateless networking apps.

Comment: @jeffbRTC -- Well, that sounds exactly like the situation I was in.  Bite the bullet, remove the code from the destructors, and figure out another way to destroy the sockets (maybe use shared pointers or some sort of reference counting scheme).  If you don't do that, you will go nuts trying to plug all the holes -- it would be like playing whack-a-mole.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie No, I don't destroy the socket from destructors. I don't even have a code inside destructors other than this debugy print statement. The socket get destroyed as soon as after Disconnect event get invoked.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie To be specific with you, I use Seastar networking library. This classes are thin wrappers around that library. Seastar does most stuff under hood.

Comment: ok, so is there a real issue in the destructor being called?  If there isn't, then there is nothing to worry about.  If there is, then you're in the same situation, just a different variation.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I thought that's the case because I couldn't come up with anything else. Based on my testing, the seg fault happens right after destructor get called. It's not something under my control too. Seastar is like it's own mini OS with it's memory management stuff.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Whacking moles is prohibited on this site ... particularly A Mole. ;)

Comment: I think You're gonna be OK Paul was recommending that people AVOID playing whack-a-mole.

Comment: @AdrianMole -- Stick an accent on the 'e', and you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: @user4581301 Frankly, I'm not okay hence the question.

Comment: @jeffbRTC your program crashes there, but it might be the result of a corruption that happened much, much earlier in its execution.

Comment: @jeffbRTC -- It could be that the object is invalid and still being referred to in some way.   What made the object invalid is a different story, and probably one that has nothing to do with the destructor.

Comment: Apologies, Jeff. I was addressing Adrian and his worries of getting whacked. And Frank was my grandfather, not me.

Comment: "move and references" are not a cure for segfaults. They are not a universal solution to bugs and will, at most, provide work-arounds and defer the bugs until later. No segfault will be solved by an extra move, or a reference, somewhere.

Comment: If you copy or move an unknown class, you might need to validate that it support those operations... Have you tried simple code with no move/copy and no thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to store an item in the `unordered_map` you need to create its copy for the map and [try_emplace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/try_emplace) does it: *the element is constructed as value_type*.

So, you get another copy of the Socket object when you execute:

```
const auto& [connection, inserted] = connections.try_emplace("A");
```

If you question is more about why [std::move](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) doesn't help here, it is more about the state of the object moved from: *Unless otherwise specified, all standard library objects that have been moved from are placed in a "valid but unspecified state", meaning the object's class invariants hold (so functions without preconditions, such as the assignment operator, can be safely used on the object after it was moved from)*. The same goes to your class, which means that the object in main function is still exists and the destructor must be called.